# Chrome is rendering image-size slightly differently?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

http://www.public.asu.edu/~dscolli1/photography/collins.html

If you view the webpage on Chrome, it displays the four images side-by-side like a gallery. However, I tested the page in IE, Firefox, and Safari, and the fourth image of the ballpark drops to the next line and causes the page to be uneven. I noticed that the image sizes are slightly bigger in the other three browsers as well.

I have never had an issue like this? Does Chrome render image sizes differently?

```
<body>

<header>
    <img class="logo" src="Collins.png" />
</header>

<section class="imagecontainer">

    <div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="Tettegouche-.jpg">
    <img src="Tettegouche-.jpg" alt="Tettegouche State Park">
  </a>

</div>

<div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="grove.jpg">
    <img src="grove.jpg" alt="Spring Grove">
  </a>

</div>

<div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="oceandrive.jpg">
    <img src="oceandrive.jpg" alt="Lake Michigan Sunrise">
  </a>

</div>

<div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="Reds.jpg">
    <img src="Reds.jpg" alt="GABP">
  </a>

</div>

</section>

<section class="container">
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/dxcc17/"><img class="icons"     
src="instagram.png" /></a>
    <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/131549031@N04/"><img   
class="icons" src="Flickr.png" /></a>
</section>

</body>
</html>


@import url(reset.css);


body {
background-color: #e6e6e6;
}
header {
margin-top: 75px;
padding-bottom: 50px;
}
img.logo {
margin: auto;
display: block;
}

section.imagecontainer {
margin: auto auto auto 125px;
}

div.img {
padding: 5px;
opacity: 0.50;
display: inline-block;
width: 600px;
height: 400px;
}

div.img img {
height: 400px;
width: 100%;
}

div.img:hover {
opacity: 1.0;
}

.container {
padding-top: 50px;
width: 275px;
margin: auto;
}

img.icons {
display: inline-block;
margin: auto auto 20px auto;
padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Make sure you didn’t zoom the page in or out.

Comment: Tested again and made sure all of the browsers were at 100%. Same problem.

Comment: 110% zoom on Chrome matches the view of the other browsers at 100%, though.

Answer (score 0):

No one has mentioned this yet, but browsers have different rules on how they treat certain tags, such as adding margin or padding by default.

To make sure that there are no differences in other browsers, remove all margin and padding before you add any styling. 
This can be done with a Reset Stylesheet. Google/Bing it or simply click [here](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/) for one.

Comment: I already had a reset imported. I seemed to have solved the issue. I resized the images so that are two lines instead of trying to cram the four images inside of a single line. I placed each image inside of a div container attributed to the same class. I was adding margin rules for the div containers which was throwing everything out of wack. Instead, I wrapped the four div containers into a section and applied margin rules to that section instead.

Comment: Chrome is still displaying weirdly. The image gallery is still sitting slightly off to the left, but I have the page aligned correctly in IE, Safari, and Firefox.

Comment: I just tried it in chrome and in edge and it looks exactly the same to me. I noticed that you said that you had three images with one dropping down. For me two stay where they are, and two drop down. Can I see some of the html and css code? It seems that your <section> tag isn't properly holding image divs inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced image distortion still today with the logo image on my webpage. I just wrapped the logo image in a div and it has solved the issue.

```
<div class="logo-container">
  <img class="logo-img" src="./images/logo.svg" alt="logo">
</div>
```

I added the following CSS:

```
.logo-container {
    width: 10%;
    height: auto;
    align-self: center;
    margin-left: 6.5rem;
}

.logo-img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

many people are experiencing the problem.This might be due to latest chrome update.There might be a bug and i hope someone from google will solve this issue in the future.